# How to implement animated emoticons in Universal Windows Project?

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, emoticons

I'm working on a UWP using Visual Studio Community 2015. The project will be a chat application.

I need to implement high quality animated emoticons in the app. Using WebView with GIF images is not desirable, due to quality loss. Adding each emoticon as a separate image, animating each one with a storyboard (from image frames), and building the other content around that would be very ineffective, especially on devices with less memory.

Is there any other approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Win2D and especially CanvasSpriteBatch, I suppose it should provide performance you need. You have a sample which use SpriteSheet in the gallery.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D-Samples/tree/master/ExampleGallery/UAP/SpriteSheets

Comment: Win2D looks nice, but the SpriteSheets example throws OutOfMemoryException on Win 10 Mobile Emulator. I'll look further into it. Thanks.

Comment: I have made a canvas grid from which to select the emoticons. I'll use RichEditBox to compose the message (there the emoticons are not animated, but that's ok). Binding a canvas with single animated image amidst the text in a RichTextBlock works nicely. I'll test more, but ultimately this is the approach I'll use.